# form_tag inside a form_tag - In rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I wanted to use two form_tag in rails like this,

```
<%= form_tag %>

    <%= form_tag %>
    ................
    <%= submit_tag %>

<% submit_tag %>
```

But the action for inside form_tag taking first form_tag's action...!!!
For both form_tag assign the different action?

Comment: You can not use nested form.

Answer (score 5):

[HTML does not allow nested forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms), thus it's reasonable that the helpers are not designed to support nesting.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is called **Nested Forms ** take a look at the rails cast [#196 Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Here is a link to a gem that you can use to help you out https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form